# Touchable area of HTML buttons is too large in Android browser

Tags: android, html, button, touch, dom-events

We are having a problem with HTML buttons in the Android browser stealing touch events from the surrounding area.  It seems like the browser, or the native UI, gives HTML buttons a larger click area than the size of the button displayed on the screen and the button steals touch events that should be captured by nearby areas.  The problem occurs on the Android emulator as well as the various hardware platforms.  Here's an example web page:

Below, div1 is the top darker rectangle (with the text) and div2 is the bottom lighter
rectangle (with the button).

- We click in div1 (red dot indicator)
- The touch event is delivered to div1
- The mouse events are delivered to the button and div2
- We would have expected all events to be delivered to div1

[image]

Here is another example using the same page.

- We clicked in div2 at the red dot
- The touch event was delivered to div2
- The mouse events were delivered to div1
- We expected all events to be delivered to div2

[image]

We have examined the source code for Android and the Android Browser(including webkit) looking for 
an explanation for this behavior, but haven't found it.  We've also been searching the web for anyone 
else reporting this problem and have not found any mention of it!

We are looking for some type of hint that might help us here... 
Perhaps a meta tag for the fuzzy-focus?  Or a CSS style that would reduce this click-stealing behavior?

Any ideas would be much appreciated, this characteristic makes our web app very frustrating to use.

Here is the code for the page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" >

<title>Android click target test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var div1;
  var div2;
  var button1;

  // OnLoad, install event listeners for touch events, synthesized mouse events, and click events
  function doLoad(e) {
      div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
      div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
      button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
      messages = document.getElementById('messages');

      div1.addEventListener("touchstart", touch_emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("touchend", touch_emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("mousedown", emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("mouseup", emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("mouseover", emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("mouseout", emsg, false);
      div1.addEventListener("click", emsg, false);

      div2.addEventListener("touchstart", touch_emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("touchend", touch_emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("mousedown", emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("mouseup", emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("mouseover", emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("mouseout", emsg, false);
      div2.addEventListener("click", emsg, false);

      button1.addEventListener("touchstart", touch_emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("touchend", touch_emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("mousedown", emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("mouseup", emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("mouseover", emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("mouseout", emsg, false);
      button1.addEventListener("click", emsg, false);
  }

  // Messages ring-buffer
  var messages;
  var lines = 0;

  function emsg(e) {
    text = "";
    text += e.type + "(" + ((e.clientX==undefined)?"?":e.clientX) + "," + ((e.clientY==undefined)?"?":e.clientY) + ")";
    if (e.target.id != undefined) {text += " " + e.target.id;}
    if (e.currentTarget != undefined && e.currentTarget.id != undefined) {text += "::" + e.currentTarget.id;}
    msg(text);
  }

  function touch_emsg(e) {
    if (e.targetTouches != undefined) {
        var touch = e.targetTouches[0];
    }
    text = "";
    text += e.type;
    if (touch != undefined) {text += "(" + ((touch.clientX==undefined)?"?":touch.clientX) + "," + ((touch.clientY==undefined)?"?":touch.clientY) + ")";}
    if (e.target.id != undefined) {text += " " + e.target.id;}
    if (e.currentTarget != undefined && e.currentTarget.id != undefined) {text += "::" + e.currentTarget.id;}
    msg(text);
  }

  function msg(text) {
    lines++;
    if (lines > 15) {clearmsg();}
    messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" +  " " + text;
  }

  function clearmsg() {
    lines = 0;
    messages.innerHTML = "";
  }

</script>

</head>


<body onload="doLoad()">

<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color:#c0c0c0; z-index:1;">
    div1 text
</div>

<div id="div2" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 30px; width: 200px; height: 40px; background-color:#f0f0f0; z-index:2;">
    <button id="button1"> button 1 </button>
</div>

<button id="clearbutton" style="float:right;" onclick="clearmsg();">Clear</button>
<div id="messages" style="position:relative; top:65px; background-color:#aaaaff"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Getting same issues in our app.  Very frustrating.  Have discovered the problem?

Comment: Not yet.  I am reading through the Webcore code to figure out where it is "fixing" the touch events to map them to the nearest native widget. Note that on Android, Buttons are a form of TextView, and TextViews are what attract the touches away from where they belong.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem with our website here. Is there any solution for this problem, e.g. some kind of meta tag?

Comment: I crawled all over the source code for WebView and Webkit before I gave up.  The next step was going to be rebuilding the Webkit tree with debugging code in it, but we moved on to a different solution.  (We wrote a native app; the web interface was just a temporary solution any way.)  I was starting to think it had something to do with a slop calculation based on the screen density, then I gave up.

Comment: Status update.  I got a job at Google.  Now trying to befriend some guys on the Android team.  Getting closer...

Answer (score 0):

well you use z-index:2 for the div and z-index:1 for the other one  is this important? i think no.

and postion:absolute is not so good
trying relative?

well then that should be marked as done when you gave up

Comment: I'm sorry.  "marked as done"?  We have tried all combinations.  This doesn't have anything really to do with the html level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#div2, #button1 {overflow:hidden}
```